# Python3: Why are dictionaries printed in random order?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.4

Here are my two versions of python:

```
$ python --version
#=> Python 2.7.6
$ python3 --version
#=> Python 3.4.3
```

And I have this code:

```
new_dict = { 'A': ['B', 'D'], 'B': ['A', 'D', 'C'], 'C': ['B'], 'D': ['A', 'B'], 'E' : [] }
print(new_dict)
```

And here is the output from running it a couple times

```
$ python3 test.py
#=> {'A': ['B', 'D'], 'E': [], 'B': ['A', 'D', 'C'], 'C': ['B'], 'D': ['A', 'B']}
$ python3 test.py
#=> {'B': ['A', 'D', 'C'], 'C': ['B'], 'E': [], 'D': ['A', 'B'], 'A': ['B', 'D']}
$ python3 test.py
#=> {'B': ['A', 'D', 'C'], 'A': ['B', 'D'], 'D': ['A', 'B'], 'C': ['B'], 'E': []}
$ python3 test.py
#=> {'C': ['B'], 'B': ['A', 'D', 'C'], 'E': [], 'A': ['B', 'D'], 'D': ['A', 'B']}
```

I don't understand why the dictionary is out of order when it's printed.
Running it on Python 2.7.6 works fine:

```
$ python test.py
#=> {'A': ['B', 'D'], 'C': ['B'], 'B': ['A', 'D', 'C'], 'E': [], 'D': ['A', 'B']}
$ python test.py
#=> {'A': ['B', 'D'], 'C': ['B'], 'B': ['A', 'D', 'C'], 'E': [], 'D': ['A', 'B']}
$ python test.py
#=> {'A': ['B', 'D'], 'C': ['B'], 'B': ['A', 'D', 'C'], 'E': [], 'D': ['A', 'B']}
$ python test.py
#=> {'A': ['B', 'D'], 'C': ['B'], 'B': ['A', 'D', 'C'], 'E': [], 'D': ['A', 'B']}
```

Comment: By definition, a dictionary maps one value to another and thus there is no need to maintain order as per its usability as a means of encryption and decryption. Use a collection of ordered pairs instead.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi Thank you

Comment: Yep, if you need any clarification let me know.

Comment: @Malik Brahimi @DC00 if you need to maintain an order, you can use `OrderedDict` from `collections` module.